# Live Audio Streaming alternatives *without* Flash, Silverlight

Tags: flash, silverlight, streaming, live

What , if any, alternatives are there to Flash, Silverlight, and Java applets for streaming live media?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of RTP-based streaming such as RTSP(as previously mentioned), SAP and also SIP.

There are also HTTP based methods such as HTTP Live Streaming (as used by iPhone) and Smooth Streaming (as used by silverlight), there is also TS over UDP.

In short, there are many many ways to stream multimedia between computers. Depending on your requirements, which you didn't mention, the best option[s] can be chosen. Maybe you expect the video to be played in a webbrowser, or perhaps with a reliable TCP transport. Maybe you want something cross platform. Maybe you want multicast. I just don't know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream live media, you could use [Darwin Streaming Server](http://developer.apple.com/darwin/projects/streaming/) to stream it over RTSP/HTTP

> Darwin Streaming Server (DSS), is the first open sourced RTP/RTSP streaming server. It was released March 16, 1999 and is a fully featured RTSP/RTP media streaming server capable of streaming a variety of media types including H.264/MPEG-4 AVC, MPEG-4 Part 2 and 3GP.

Comment: What would be at the client side? Can browsers without html-5 support play this streamed content?

Comment: @Amarghosh The client side would be an RTSP client. The Quicktime, VLC, and windows media player plugins are RTSP clients.